# How many n digit numbers are there which start with a given pattern?

Tags: combinatorics

There is a 7 digit code which can't start with 0. How many codes are there which start with 324?
How can I solve it?

Comment: What is a variation?  Do you mean permutation?  I wouldn't say it was either a combination or a permutation.  If the code is $7$ digits long and starts with $324$ then you have $4$ more digits to fill in.  How many ways can you do this?

Comment: @Bram28 I'm not sure that's right.  It reads to me like there are two separate questions, so I don't think there's a double-counting issue.

Comment: OP: should it be how many codes start with 324 or end with 25?  Or are these two separate questions?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that they are separate questions. What I'd like to find out is that in a 7 digit code how many can start with 324?

Comment: @Paralyz3d OK .. so maybe you should just stick with that question and remove the whole bit about ending with $25$ .. that's also more consistent with your title. And, when you know how to answer the first question, the second question is easy since the method will be pretty much the same (just need to think about that $0$ at the start ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you had 7 digits that are free to be anything.  But if the first three were fixed and they have to be 324 then you have four digits remaining that can be anything.

How many options are there to assign to 4 digits?

There are ten choice for the first one, and for each  of those ten choices there are ten choices for the second,  and for each of those pairs in the ten groups of ten choices there ten choices for the third....

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are $10$ possibilities for each of the remaining $4$ numbers. There are $10$ digits to choose from to specify the fourth digit, similarly for the rest. So there are $10^4$ such codes.

Comment: @timtfj: Thanks! Corrected